# Laravel Livewire Display Data to a Dynamic Page

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Hello guys I am trying to create a dynamic page where it would only display filtered(sort of report generation) for the selected instructor. The thing is when I try to return a view in the show method the dynamic page doesn't show up no errors. Tried dd() it shows correct data.
**How can I refactor the controller so that it would also display(render) the dynamic page called in show() ?** I am quite new to Laravel and Livewire.

This is my Controller

{

```
use WithPagination;

public  $user_id;
public function render()
{
    $showInstructors = DB::table('emp_info')
    ->leftjoin('list_unit', 'emp_info.unitID', '=','list_unit.unitid')
    ->leftjoin('list_pos', 'emp_info.posID', '=','list_pos.posID')
    ->leftjoin('emp_status', 'emp_info.statID', '=','emp_status.statid')
    ->select('emp_info.*','list_unit.unitname','list_pos.position','emp_status.shortname')
    ->paginate(10);
    return view('livewire.instructor-report',compact('showInstructors'));

}
    public function show($user_id)
    {
        $showIdentification=DB::table('emp_info')
        ->leftjoin('list_unit', 'emp_info.unitID', '=','list_unit.unitid')
        ->leftjoin('list_pos', 'emp_info.posID', '=','list_pos.posID')
        ->leftjoin('emp_status', 'emp_info.statID', '=','emp_status.statid')
        ->where('user_id', $user_id)
        ->select('emp_info.*','list_unit.unitname','list_pos.position','emp_status.shortname')
        ->get();
    
         $downloadSched=
        DB::table('load_schedule')
        ->leftjoin('emp_info', 'load_schedule.faculty_id', '=','emp_info.user_id')
        ->where('faculty_id',  $user_id)
        ->select('load_schedule.corsdes','load_Schedule.corsno','load_schedule.unit','load_schedule.room','load_schedule.day','load_schedule.c_time','load_schedule.size')
        ->orderBy('corsno')
        ->get();
        dd($showIdentification, $downloadSched);
        
    }
```

}

}

---

web routes

```
Route::get('/sched-report',ScheduleReport::class)->name('sched-report')->middleware(['auth']);
Route::get('/sched-report/{user_id}',ScheduleReport::class, 'show')->middleware(['auth']);
```

Comment: Where do you want to render your data ? I mean in another page, or on the current page with modal ?

Comment: Render to another page